# django sitemap custom template response format is not in xml

Tags: python, xml, django, sitemap

I try to override existing sitemap template to enable deep link, but response format not in xml.
    **urls.py**

```
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$',sitemap,{'sitemaps':sitemaps,'template_name':'sitemaps/sitemap.xml','content_type':'application/xml'},name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap')
```

**sitemap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
{% spaceless %}
{% for url in urlset %}
<url>
<loc>{{ url.location }}</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" href="android-app://{{ url.location }}" />
{% if url.lastmod %}<lastmod>{{ url.lastmod|date:"Y-m-d" }}</lastmod> {% endif %}
{% if url.changefreq %}<changefreq>{{ url.changefreq }}</changefreq>{% endif %}
{% if url.priority %}<priority>{{ url.priority }}</priority>{% endif %}
</url>
{% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
</urlset>
```

please help, am not getting not solution from google.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a `/` at the end of the namespace definition worked for me. This is the way I use the tag:
`<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/">`